# Image size (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, size

I would like to get the Image size in python,as I do it with c++.

```
int w = src->width;
printf("%d", 'w');
```

Comment: What's that `->` syntax for? Never seen it before...

Comment: For accessing an object's properties like in PHP? If so, why don't they just use the dot operator (`.`)?

Comment: @YatharthROCK In C++ `a->b` is the equivalent of `(*a).b`

Comment: @GabiPurcaru OK, so what does the `*` operator do then? in Python it unpacked a tuple or list...

Comment: I don't know the technical name for it, but it turns a pointer (don't even ask what that is!) into the thing it points to

Comment: it's called dereferencing, and allows us to access to the value of the variable pointed by the * operator

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the function [`GetSize`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/core_operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=getsize#GetSize) from the module `cv` with your image as parameter. It returns width, height as a tuple with 2 elements:

```
width, height = cv.GetSize(src)
```

Comment: This function doesn't seem to exist in OpenCV 3. Maybe it was removed a while ago?

Comment: Link seems broken

Comment: It looks like this function has been depreciated.

Answer (score 151):

Using openCV and numpy it is as easy as this:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('path/to/img',0)
height, width = img.shape[:2]
```

Comment: Why does `numpy` need to be imported for this?

Comment: it uses numpy internally

Answer (score 30):

For me the easiest way is to take all the values returned by image.shape:

```
height, width, channels = img.shape
```

if you don't want the number of channels (useful to determine if the image is bgr or grayscale) just drop the value:

```
height, width, _ = img.shape
```

Answer (score 18):

I use numpy.size() to do the same:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
height = np.size(image, 0)
width = np.size(image, 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

from this tutorial:
https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-get-image-size/

```
import cv2

# read image
img = cv2.imread('/home/ubuntu/Walnut.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# get dimensions of image
dimensions = img.shape

# height, width, number of channels in image

height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]
channels = img.shape[2]
```

---

from this other tutorial:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/19/opencv-tutorial-a-guide-to-learn-opencv/

> image = cv2.imread("jp.png")
>
> (h, w, d) = image.shape

Please double check things before posting answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that returns the image dimensions:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

def get_image_dimensions(imagefile):
    """
    Helper function that returns the image dimentions

    :param: imagefile str (path to image)
    :return dict (of the form: {width:<int>, height=<int>, size_bytes=<size_bytes>)
    """
    # Inline import for PIL because it is not a common library
    with Image.open(imagefile) as img:
        # Calculate the width and hight of an image
        width, height = img.size

    # calculat ethe size in bytes
    size_bytes = os.path.getsize(imagefile)

    return dict(width=width, height=height, size_bytes=size_bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe simply `img.shape[-1::-1]` would be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `image.shape` to get the dimensions of the image. It returns 3 values. The first value is height of an image, the second is width, and the last one is number of channels. You don't need the last value here so you can use below code to get height and width of image:

```py
height, width = src.shape[:2]
print(width, height)
```