# can't open an image inserted in another image

Tags: python, image

I want to insert an image in another image, I have been able to do so using, per example, `img=open('logo.png')` as inserted image and background image  `background=open('backgroundImg.png')` but when I want to work with `askopenfilename` I get this error :

```
background.paste(img, offset)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'paste'
```

here is my code :

```
from PIL import Image
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import cv2

filename1 = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("image","*.png")])
filename2 = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("image","*.png")])
img=cv2.imread(filename1,1)
background=cv2.imread(filename2,1)
img_w, img_h =img.shape[:2]
bg_w, bg_h = background.shape[:2]
offset = ((bg_w - img_w) // 2, (bg_h - img_h) // 2)
background.paste(img, offset)
background.save('savedImg/output.png')
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23207185/3462319

Comment: Thank u, problem solved, but I had a now error
` AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'paste'`

Comment: what about that error don't you understand? this is a different question and should not be asked in the comments of this one

Comment: okay, sorry 
I'll post another question.
Thank u for ur help